# R2 for several fixed effects models using fixest::feols and modelsummary

Tags: r, fixed, effects, modelsummary

I have a dataset

```
structure(list(NAME_1.y = c("Alibori", "Atakora", "Atlantique", 
"Borgou", "Collines", "Donga", "Kouffo", "Littoral", "Mono", 
"Oueme", "Plateau", "Zou", "Central", "Chobe", "Francistown", 
"Gaborone", "Ghanzi", "Jwaneng", "Kgalagadi", "Kgatleng", "Kweneng", 
"Lobatse", "North-East", "Selibe Phikwe", "South-East", "Southern", 
"Mosteiros", "Paúl", "Porto Novo", "Praia", "Ribeira Grande", 
"Santa Catarina", "Santa Cruz", "Sao Domingos", "Sao Filipe", 
"Sao Miguel", "Sao Vicente", "Tarrafal", "Ashanti", "Brong Ahafo", 
"Central", "Eastern", "Greater Accra", "Northern", "Upper East", 
"Upper West", "Volta", "Western", "Bomet", "Bungoma"), country = c("Benin", 
"Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", 
"Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", 
"Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", 
"Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Cape Verde", 
"Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", 
"Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", 
"Cape Verde", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", 
"Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Kenya", "Kenya"), year = c(2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005), yearvalue = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), sngq = c(40.3350714285714, 41.8501465773809, 32.1462559523809, 
53.3881378348214, 51.3143125, 45.3290479910714, 30.9222321428571, 
31.8178055555556, 29.6696517857143, 32.6099506302521, 30.4012254464286, 
31.2331401098901, 48.3522208850932, 46.2751339285714, 51.8882346938775, 
49.0520504201681, 49.9850803571429, 49.7569285714286, 48.6707276785714, 
55.5698392857143, 49.1367147108843, 49.6709583333333, 47.7482008928571, 
47.4158928571429, 47.1282232142857, 47.5937851190476, 45.5919585253456, 
39.4586860119048, 34.0096227106227, 37.4234026227679, 35.2635037202381, 
36.663, 39.3566339285714, 39.9424339285714, 38.4452915543576, 
41.0157392857143, 46.5320122818358, 45.8783482142857, 45.1649102484472, 
55.3813660714286, 40.4874038461538, 43.992073015873, 39.0866451990632, 
54.0252091836735, 48.2392232142857, 45.3506232142857, 43.0489608516484, 
36.9757994047619, 38.9841964285714, 36.4050892857143), fac = c(0.365909090909091, 
0.39375, 0.609722222222222, 0.525, 0.664583333333333, 0.546875, 
0.322727272727273, 0.574603174603175, 0.5, 0.633823529411765, 
0.5, 0.428846153846154, 0.344836956521739, 0.3, 0.246428571428571, 
0.169117647058824, 0.733333333333333, 1, 0.7125, 0.428571428571429, 
0.35952380952381, 0.0833333333333333, 0.4, 0, 0.24, 0.381666666666667, 
0.341935483870968, 0.466666666666667, 0.302564102564103, 0.1890625, 
0.35, 0.48, 0.354545454545455, 0.48, 0.323270440251572, 0.35, 
0.323076923076923, 0.233333333333333, 0.508188405797101, 0.641071428571429, 
0.686057692307692, 0.759012345679012, 0.460326086956522, 0.475, 
0.476190476190476, 0.50125, 0.459615384615385, 0.65875, 0.1, 
0.6), svc = c(0.0909090909090909, 0.0833333333333333, 0.44212962962963, 
0.270833333333333, 0.25, 0.166666666666667, 0.299242424242424, 
0.682539682539683, 0.333333333333333, 0.436274509803922, 0.333333333333333, 
0.384615384615385, 0.560688405797101, 0.833333333333333, 0.973214285714286, 
0.742647058823529, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.797619047619048, 0.507936507936508, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.833333333333333, 0.933333333333333, 0.561111111111111, 0.301075268817204, 
0.833333333333333, 0.534188034188034, 0.657552083333333, 0.638888888888889, 
0.355555555555556, 0.424242424242424, 0.466666666666667, 0.30188679245283, 
0.333333333333333, 0.933634992458522, 0.666666666666667, 0.515942028985507, 
0.523809523809524, 0.756410256410256, 0.511111111111111, 0.947463768115942, 
0.37797619047619, 0.541666666666667, 0.391666666666667, 0.5, 
0.733333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.191666666666667)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(
    year = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
    2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
    2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
    2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
    2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
    2005, 2005), country = c("Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", 
    "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", 
    "Benin", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", 
    "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", 
    "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", "Botswana", 
    "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", 
    "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", 
    "Cape Verde", "Cape Verde", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", 
    "Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Ghana", "Kenya", 
    "Kenya"), NAME_1.y = c("Alibori", "Atakora", "Atlantique", 
    "Borgou", "Collines", "Donga", "Kouffo", "Littoral", "Mono", 
    "Oueme", "Plateau", "Zou", "Central", "Chobe", "Francistown", 
    "Gaborone", "Ghanzi", "Jwaneng", "Kgalagadi", "Kgatleng", 
    "Kweneng", "Lobatse", "North-East", "Selibe Phikwe", "South-East", 
    "Southern", "Mosteiros", "Paúl", "Porto Novo", "Praia", 
    "Ribeira Grande", "Santa Catarina", "Santa Cruz", "Sao Domingos", 
    "Sao Filipe", "Sao Miguel", "Sao Vicente", "Tarrafal", "Ashanti", 
    "Brong Ahafo", "Central", "Eastern", "Greater Accra", "Northern", 
    "Upper East", "Upper West", "Volta", "Western", "Bomet", 
    "Bungoma"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
        7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
        19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
        30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
        41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -50L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I want to estimate a fixed effects regression with cumulative stepwise addition of controls and have the results show in a `modelsummary` table.

```
library(fixest)

model <- feols(sngq ~ csw(yearvalue, fac, svc) | country + year + country^year, df) 

names(model) <- c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", "Model 4")

modelsummary(model, coef_omit = "Int", stars = c("***" = 0.01, "**" = 0.05, "*" = 0.1), gof_omit = "IC$|Lik.|RMSE|FE", coef_rename = c("yearvalue" = "Extraction Value", "fac" = "Nearby Facilities", "svc" = "Available Services"))
```

Unfortunately, this does not show the R2 for each respective model.
I know I can calculate the R2 for a single model using

```
r2(feols(sngq ~ yearvalue + fac + svc | country + year + country^year, df), "r2")
```

but I would like it included in the `modelsummary` table for multiple models as a normal goodness of fit item, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this bug was fixed in upstream packages. If you install the latest development versions you should be able to get R2 automatically:

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("lrberge/fixest")
install_github("easystats/performance")
install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")
```

Restart R completely, then:

```r
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)

mod <- feols(mpg ~ sw(hp, wt, drat) | cyl, data = mtcars)

modelsummary(mod, output = "markdown")
```

|  | rhs: hp | rhs: wt | rhs: drat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hp | -0.024 |  |  |
|  | (0.015) |  |  |
| wt |  | -3.206 |  |
|  |  | (1.188) |  |
| drat |  |  | 1.793 |
|  |  |  | (1.564) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 | 32 |
| R2 | 0.754 | 0.837 | 0.745 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.727 | 0.820 | 0.718 |
| R2 Within | 0.080 | 0.392 | 0.048 |
| R2 Within Adj. | 0.047 | 0.371 | 0.014 |
| AIC | 163.9 | 150.6 | 165.0 |
| BIC | 166.8 | 153.6 | 167.9 |
| RMSE | 2.94 | 2.39 | 2.99 |
| Std.Errors | by: cyl | by: cyl | by: cyl |
| FE: cyl | X | X | X |

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to execute ```install_github("lrberge/fixest") ```, it gives me: ```Downloading GitHub repo lrberge/fixest@HEAD
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/lrberge/fixest/tarball/HEAD' failed```

Comment: Is there any way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: Nevermind, I tried it again today and it worked perfectly! Thank you!