# `modelsummary::msummary()` does not produce R2 after running `fixest::feols`

Tags: r, modelsummary, fixest

I found the same issue here: [R2 for several fixed effects models using fixest::feols and modelsummary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72829109/r2-for-several-fixed-effects-models-using-fixestfeols-and-modelsummary)

I followed the suggestion provided and it solved my problem on Windows. But this did not solve the problem on my Mac. In fact, after running the following snippet, `msummary()` stopped showing results in the Viewer tab of RStudio. It was able to generate a Word file with the results, but those results did not include R2. If I remove the argument `output = "file name"` from `msummary()`, I can see the results (without R2) on the Viewer tab.

```
library(remotes)
install_github("lrberge/fixest")
install_github("easystats/performance")
install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")
```

Any insights will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What package versions does `sessionInfo()` print?

Comment: @Vincent I think this is what you wanted to see? ```other attached packages:
 [1] remotes_2.4.2           labelled_2.10.0         gtsummary_1.6.1        
 [4] plm_2.6-2               car_3.1-0               carData_3.0-5          
 [7] readxl_1.4.1            modelsummary_1.0.2.9000 fixest_0.10.4          
[10] forcats_0.5.2           stringr_1.4.1           dplyr_1.0.10           
[13] purrr_0.3.4             readr_2.1.2             tidyr_1.2.1            
[16] tibble_3.1.8            ggplot2_3.3.6           tidyverse_1.3.2        
```

Comment: This shows that the installation from Github using the commands above did not work, because the dev version of `fixest` is 0.10.5. Please install again, restart R, and try again.

Comment: @Vincent thanks for pointing that out. I finally managed to install ```fixest``` properly using the following codes: ```options(download.file.method = "curl")
install_github("lrberge/fixest")```.